# Self joining query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, self-join

We are exploring the possibility of migrating from relational database to MongoDB and having difficulty dealing with a query, the data schema is like this:

```
data_store:
    id,
    userId,
    study,
    form,
    formData: {
        element1: value1,
        element2: value2,
        .....
    }
```

formData is a json array of dynamic element:value pairs, different form has a different list of pre-defined elements.

The requirement is by given 2 forms in a study, we need to display all their elements' data in one row for the same user, i.e. we need to join by userId and display the formData in a flat structure.

Also one user may have multiple data entry for the same form, so if a user has 3 entries for form A and 4 entries for form B, we expect that there are 12 rows for them in the result.

Sample data:

```
id: "id1",
user: "user1",
study: "study",
form: "f1",
formData: [
    { "e11": "value1" },
    { "e12": "value2" },
    { "e13": "value3" }
]
```

,

```
id: "id2",
user: "user1",
study: "study",
form: "f1",
formData: [
    { "e11": "value4" },
    { "e12": "value5" },
    { "e13": "value6" }
]
```

,

```
id: "id3",
user: "user1",
study: "study",
form: "f2",
formData: [
    { "e21": "value7" },
    { "e22": "value8" }
]
```

,

```
id: "id4",
user: "user1",
study: "study1",
form: "f2",
formData: [
    { "e21": "value9" },
    { "e22": "value10" }
]
```

,

```
id: "id2",
user: "user2",
study: "study1",
form: "f2",
formData: [
    { "e21": "value11" },
    { "e22": "value12" }
```

The expected result for the sample data above is:

| Row# | study | user | f1.e11 | f1.e12 | f1.e13 | f2.e21 | f2.e22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | study | user1 | value1 | value2 | value3 | value7 | value8 |
| 2 | study | user1 | value1 | value2 | value3 | value9 | value10 |
| 3 | study | user1 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 |
| 4 | study | user1 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value9 | value10 |
| 5 | study | user2 |  |  |  | value11 | value12 |

A similar query in relational database may be like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from data_store t1, data_store t2
where t1.form = 'f1'
and t2.form = 'f2'
and t1.userId = t2.userId;
```

I am having difficulty of converting it into MongoDB query, any one who can shed some light will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is easy using MongoDB, you just have to make use of MongoDB Aggregation with $unwind and $project stages. Let me know if you want a code sample, and share a sample data with garbage values which I can work on, along with sample output in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have updated the question with sample data and desired output.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below Aggregation Query to get the desired result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "user": "$user",
        "form": "$form",
        
      },
      "formData": {
        "$push": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$formData",
            [
              {
                "study": "$study"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "user": "$_id.user",
        
      },
      formData: {
        "$push": "$formData"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "formData": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$formData",
              0
            ]
          },
          "as": "f1",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$gt": [
                  {
                    "$size": "$formData"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$formData",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  "as": "f2",
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$$f1",
                      "$$f2"
                    ],
                    
                  },
                  
                },
                
              },
              "else": [
                "$$f1"
              ]
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$formData",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$formData",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "user": "$_id.user"
          },
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$formData",
              "initialValue": {},
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ],
                
              }
            },
            
          },
          
        ],
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Working Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mp1ct4MAK1A)

Let me know if you want an explanation of each stage.

**Limitations:**
This will work only if there are two forms of studies `f1` and `f2`.

I am working on making this dynamic and will update this answer once done.

**EDIT:**

Make use of this updated query which will work dynamically.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "form": {
        "$in": [
          "f1",
          "f2"
        ]
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "formData": {
        "$push": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$formData",
                "initialValue": {},
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      "$arrayToObject": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": {
                            "$objectToArray": "$$this"
                          },
                          "as": "formValue",
                          "in": {
                            "k": {
                              "$concat": [
                                "$form",
                                "-",
                                "$$formValue.k"
                              ]
                            },
                            "v": "$$formValue.v"
                          }
                        },
                        
                      },
                      
                    },
                    
                  ]
                },
                
              }
            },
            {
              "study": "$study",
              "user": "$user",
              "form": "$form"
            },
            
          ],
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "formData": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$size": "$formData"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            $reduce: {
              input: {
                $range: [
                  0,
                  {
                    $size: "$formData"
                  }
                ]
              },
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $let: {
                      vars: {
                        i: "$$this"
                      },
                      in: {
                        $map: {
                          input: {
                            $range: [
                              {
                                $add: [
                                  1,
                                  "$$i"
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                $size: "$formData"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          in: [
                            {
                              "$let": {
                                "vars": {
                                  "arrayElem1": {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                      "$formData",
                                      "$$i"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  "arrayElem2": {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                      "$formData",
                                      "$$this"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  
                                },
                                "in": {
                                  "$cond": {
                                    "if": {
                                      "$and": [
                                        {
                                          "$ne": [
                                            "$$arrayElem1.form",
                                            "$$arrayElem2.form"
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        //     {
                                        //       "$eq": [
                                        //         "$$arrayElem1.user",
                                        //         "$$arrayElem2.user"
                                        //        ]
                                        //      },
                                        
                                      ],
                                      
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                      "$mergeObjects": [
                                        "$$arrayElem2",
                                        "$$arrayElem1",
                                        
                                      ],
                                      
                                    },
                                    "else": "$$REMOVE",
                                    
                                  },
                                  
                                },
                                
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "else": [
            "$formData"
          ]
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "formData": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$formData",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    "$ne": [
                      "$$this",
                      [
                        null
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$this",
                  "else": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$formData"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$formData"
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Playground Working Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZsTsRhMDPyY)

Comment: The challenge is to display all form elements in one row. Please see my updates in the question body. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. I am working on another query which will work with a dynamic number of forums and will update the answer. Please work on this till then.

Comment: It took me quite a while to understand each step in the pipeline.  Wondering if you figured out the solution for dynamic number of forms?  Our requirement is up to 5 forms, and user can select any formData element for sorting.

Comment: ok, will work on a dynamic number of forms possibility and let you know in 2 days.